# Laravel 7: Cron jobs for task scheduler in Cpanel not working

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm using Namecheap Hosting. And my files are in a subdomain. I've added a task scheduler in Kernel.php file and add cron jobs in hosting. But it's not working. When I manually run schedule command it works perfectly. Can anyone please see the below code and details and tell me what am I missing?

Kerner.php file:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('add:earnLeave')
        ->everyMinute()
        ->timezone('Asia/Dhaka');
    }
```

Cron Command:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /https://subdomain.maindomain.com/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

and in my hosting the minimum run time is every five minutes `*/5   *   *   *   *`
and my task scheduler will run once on the last day of the month. For testing purposes, I set it to every minute. Should I have to keep this run time equal to cron jobs?

What should I do now?

Comment: Not working, I have tried with these following commands,

`/usr/local/bin/php /https://ess.goldfxfunds.com/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`
`/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/subdomain/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

not working

Comment: Can you run only "php /home/username/public_html/subdomain/artisan"  and check it shows a list of artisan commands or not?

Make sure your path "/home/username/public_html/subdomain/artisan" is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem myself.
I use `/usr/bin/php` instead of `usr/local/bin/php`
And also proc_open was disabled. After enabling it, now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Domain name no needed.

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/laravelrootfolder/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Tried with that also. not working

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/subdomain/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Tried with that, not working.

Comment: Command is correct now but check your server php path.

Comment: My task scheduler will run on the last day of month at 11 pm. And my cron job is running every five minutes. Is there any chance to miss my scheduler?